# Pausing javascript processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works flawlessly if I uncomment the "alert"s. This is what I've figured out for doing a set of cascading dropdowns where the user selects Country, then State, then City.

With the alerts uncommented, it's like the values haven't gotten updated yet. I've tried a lot of stuff, but I've had no luck. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Country").change(function () {
        $("#City").html("");
        var id = $("#Country").val();
        getStates(id);

//      alert("CountryId = " + id);
        var stateId = $("#State").val();
//      alert("stateId = " + stateId);
        var stateId = $("#State").val();
        alert("stateId = " + stateId);

        $(document).ready(function() {
            getCities(stateId);
        });
    });
    $("#State").change(function(){
        var id = $("#State").val();
        id = (id==null)?1:id;
            getCities(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: `The following code works flawlessly if I uncomment the alerts` contradicts `With the alerts uncommented, it's like the values haven't gotten updated yet`.

Comment: edit your question and put the code for getStates in it

Comment: The problem isn't here, it's in your "getStates()" and "getCities()" functions. I bet they're making ajax calls.  Those are not synchronous.

Comment: Why are you defining a document.ready handler _inside_ your document ready handler (and inside your change handler)? The document is already ready at that point.

Comment: @nnnnnn. Maybe it's because he likes spaghetti...  =)

Answer (score 7):

If function getStates is asynchronous request to the server then you have to add success callback to it. If not it is weird.

btw. $(document).ready inside document ready doesn't make any sense.

Comment: :) That should not have been left in there. It was one of my attempts to try to make it work...

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make much sense

Perhaps this is what you mean

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Country").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    getStates(id);
  });
  $("#State").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    getCities(id);
  });
});
```